# Publishing visual studio solution with 3 projects

Tags: .net, iis

I've created a visual studio solution (.netcore 2.2) with 3 projects, Data access class (DAL), Web App1 and Web App2 that reference the Data Access Class.

How do I publish these projects in IIS, I want Web App1 and Web App2 to be separate sites, but what happens to the DAL ?

Thanks

Comment: Only web applications can be published (dotnet publish command is for that). Your DAL project is simply used as assembly reference and deployed as part of the web applications.

Comment: So will the DAL get published for each WebApp ? , In this case I will have two instances of the DAL and I thought the whole ideas is have common data layer for the web apps?

Comment: Now that your web app has already referenced the DAL, it should have been published for each web app. If you want to create a common data layer. Then you should create a web service instead of a class library.

Comment: When you say 'web service' are you referring to an API ?

Comment: @Jet I mean WCF. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf .